# Apple RealityKit: How to draw a polygon plane using ModelEntity?

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, realitykit

I used to use some SceneKit APIs such as

```
SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)

SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData,
                   primitiveType: .polygon,
                   primitiveCount: 1,
                   bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
```

or

```
SCNShape(path: bezierPath, extrusionDepth: 0.0003)
```

to implement drawing a polygon in the scene.

Nowadays I am trying to rewrite the implementation via RealityKit.
But I have only found some basic mesh APIs such as

```
generatePlane(width: Float, height: Float, cornerRadius: Float = 0) -> MeshResource
generatePlane(width: Float, depth: Float, cornerRadius: Float = 0) -> MeshResource
generateBox(size: Float, cornerRadius: Float = 0) -> MeshResource
generateSphere(radius: Float) -> MeshResource
...
```

I was hoping for something closer to SceneKit's convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RealityKit does not have APIs to create custom geometry at run time.

---

**Edit:** RealityKit 2 introduced support for dynamic meshes. See [Explore advanced rendering with RealityKit 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10075/) from WWDC21.

Comment: It seems that it really lacks these APIs.

Comment: So I have to use SceneKit?

Comment: RealityKit 2 introduced support for dynamic meshes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that demonstrates how you can generate a mesh programmatically from vertices with a [MeshDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshdescriptor):

```
let positions: [SIMD3<Float>] = [SIMD3(x:0.0,  y:0.0,  z:0.0),
                                 SIMD3(x:0.1,  y:0.01, z:0.0),
                                 SIMD3(x:0.07, y:0.07, z:0.05),
                                 SIMD3(x:0.0,  y:0.1,  z:0.0),
                                 SIMD3(x:0.05, y:0.05, z:0.0)]

let counts: [UInt8] = [5]
let indices: [UInt32] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

var meshDescriptor = MeshDescriptor()
meshDescriptor.positions = .init(positions)
meshDescriptor.primitives = .polygons(counts, indices)
let polygon = try! MeshResource.generate(from: [meshDescriptor])
```

In addition to `polygons`, RealityKit currently has two other primitive types: [`triangles`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshdescriptor/primitives-swift.enum/triangles(_:)), and [`trianglesAndQuads`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshdescriptor/primitives-swift.enum/trianglesandquads(triangles:quads:)).

For more details, see the WWDC session linked to by @mnuages in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58414173/328936), starting from [around 26m35s](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10075/?time=1594).